# Type error when running RxJS official `fromEvent` tutorial

Tags: jquery, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to run the first example here. [Rx.Observable.fromEvent(element, eventName, [selector])](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md)

But when compiling, the compiler throws me the following error.

> Uncaught exception: { [TypeScript error: index.ts(44,38): Error
>   TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Node'.   Property 'attributes' is missing in type 'JQuery'.]
>   message: 'index.ts(44,38): Error TS2345: Argument of type \'JQuery\'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type \'Node\'.\n  Property
>   \'attributes\' is missing in type \'JQuery\'.'

at

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'click');
```

The input is

```
var input = $('#input');
```

The following is my imports:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/rx/rx.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/rx/rx.async.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

import Rx = require('rx');
import $ = require('jquery');
```

Comment: so where is your `input `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'

You need to access the underlying DOM element. One way is to use the string indexer `[0]` :

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input[0], 'click');
```

Comment: Hmm looks more like the declaration is incorrect? At least the documentation explicitly states that jQuery objects are welcome, too. Declaration is inside [rx.async-lite.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571/rx/rx.async-lite.d.ts).

Comment: @Aszune's Heart Maybe you need use an official typescript file https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/ts/rx.async-lite.d.ts which contains on/off notation as in jQuery.